# Translate Database object into GraphQL object

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, gql

I am new to GraphQL and I cannot understand what is the correct way of resolving queries when the database fields are different from the GraphQL schema fields.

I am using [Apollo Server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/).

My DB schema is like this one:

```js
// db schema

type Book {
  id: number
  title: string
  author_id: number
}

type Author {
  id: number
  name: string
}
```

My GraphQL schema must be like this one:

```js
// gql schema

type Book {
  title: String!
  author: Author!
}

type Author {
  name: String!
  books: [Book]!
}

type Query {
  author(id: ID!): Author
  book(id: ID!): Book
  authors: [Author]
  books: [Book]
}
```

Now what I understood is that I have to manually translate the database object to the graphql response object with resolvers.

So these are my resolvers:

```js
const resolvers:Resolvers = {
  Book: {
    author: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const authors = await db.author.select({where: {id: parent.author_id}});
                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -> FIRST PROBLEM 
      return authors[0];
    }
  },
  Author: {
    books: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const books = await db.books.select({where: {author_id: parent.id}});
      return books;
    }
  },
  Query: {
    book: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const books = await db.author.select({where: {id: args.id}});
      return books[0];
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -> SECOND PROBLEM
    }
    author: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const authors = await db.author.select({where: {id: args.id}});
      return authors[0];
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -> SAME AS SECOND PROBLEM
    },
    books: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const books = await db.books.select();
      return books;
    }
    authors: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const authors = await db.authors.select();
      return authors;
    }

  }
}
```

FIRST PROBLEM:

When I resolve the `author` field in Book, I don't have the `author_id` fields because it is not defined in the graphql schema.
Should I always add `author_id` also in the GQL Schema?

SECOND PROBLEM:

How can I resolve the `Author` in `Query.book`? Is there a proper way to resolve it? I don't want to make another DB call, because this will lead me to an infinite loop, right?

SAME AS SECOND PROBLEM:

How can I resolve the `[Book]` in `Query.author`? Is there a proper way to resolve the it?

I put these problems together because I think they are all related to the same solutions somehow. I just cannot see it.

Can somebody know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the SECOND PROBLEM and SAME AS SECOND PROBLEMS, they are not really problems.

In those methods you can resolve every field expect for the "object type" fields, like `author` for `Book` and `books` for `Author`. You already resolved them above. The service will take care of adding them to the result.

Regarding the FIRST PROBLEM if you don't want to add `author_id` you can do something like:

```typescript
const resolvers:Resolvers = {
  Book: {
    author: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const books = await db.book.select({where: {id: parent.id}}); 
      const author_id = books[0].author_id;
      const authors = await db.author.select({where: {id: author_id}});
      return authors[0];
    }
  },
```

But with this method you are going to make 2 queries, so it might be a bit slower.

You can also resolve the Book with more attributes than what is defined in the GraphQL schema. So you can return a book object that has also the `author_id` attribute. The service won't show it but the resolver can still use it. So for example:

```typescript
const resolvers:Resolvers = {
  Book: {
    author: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const authors = await db.author.select({where: {id:parent.author_id}});
      return authors[0];
    },
    // ...
  },
  Query: {
    book: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const books = await db.author.select({where: {id: args.id}});
      return books[0];
      // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -> return a book with also `author_id`.
    },
    // ...
  }
}
```

The problem with this is that if you are using Typescript, it won't allow it, since it wants you return and object with the correct fields.